# Вертикальное выравнивание списка относительно маркеров

Tags: css

[image: List]

Код:

```css
ul.list3-1 {
counter-reset: li;
list-style: none outside none;
margin-bottom: 4em;
padding: 0;
color:#b41132;
}
ul.list3-1 li {
position: relative;
padding: 4px 0 5px 37px;
}
ul.list3-1 li:after {
content: counter(li, decimal-leading-zero);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 90%;
margin-top: -52px;
font-weight: 700;
border-radius: 100%;
color: #fff;
width: 26px;
height: 26px;
background-color:#b41132;
text-align: center;
line-height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list3-1">
 <hr>
 <li>Занятия в группах
 </li>
 <li>Индивидуальные занятия
 </li>
 <li>Интенсив-курсы ускоренного обучения
 </li>
 <li>Подготовка к ЕГЭ
 </li>
 <li>Услуги гида-переводчика
 </li>
 <li>Устный перевод
 </li>
 <li>Дистанционное обучение по Skype.
 </li>
 <li>Услуги помощи в оформлении документов мигрантам.
 </li>
 <li>Ведутся занятия с носителями языка.
Зто интересно! Звоните! Приходите!</li>
 <li>Мы смотрим фильмы на английском языке и обсуждаем их с носителями языка. Интересно! Бесплатно! Звоните! Приходите!</li>
 <li>Проводится запись на изучение КИТАЙСКОГО языка !</li>
```

Comment: Как вертикально выровнять список?

Comment: `<ul><hr>` — невалидный код. В `<ul>` напрямую должны быть вложены только `<li>` и если вам там позарез нужен `<hr>` то правильнее всего выделить под него отдельный тег  `<li><hr></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Наверное нужно наоборот - выравнивание маркеров относительно списка? Тогда это:

```
ul.list3-1 li:after {top: calc(50% - 13px}
```

Тогда маркеры будут по центру элемента списка.
Если нужно по верхнему краю, то:

```
ul.list3-1 li:after {top: 0}
```

Если по нижнему, то:

```
ul.list3-1 li:after {bottom: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте стили таким образом:

```
ul.list3-1 li:after {
content: counter(li, decimal-leading-zero);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
font-weight: 700;
border-radius: 100%;
color: #fff;
width: 26px;
height: 26px;
background-color:#b41132;
text-align: center;
line-height: 26px;
}
```